# Error when exporting Query Layers and Event Layers to Feature Class from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export

ArcEditor 10.2.2 and 10.2.0
SQL Server 2008, service pack 4

We have Query Layers and Event Layer point layers in ArcMap, which have been created from tables in a  SQL database. The layers can be displayed and symbolized in ArcGIS, but when trying to export to a file geodatabase Feature Class or a shape file we often get the error below, or get no error, but the output is blank (no data). This issue is not consistent, sometimes is working and sometimes not working.

[image: Error exporting data]

Does anyone experience this error and know the solution?

Comment: Are there any spaces or special characters in the path to the table.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a workaround...first go to the table and export as a file GDB table..then go to display XY data from the new table, and then export the data from this new event layer.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in ArcGIS 10.3, but having the same issue.  I found that the export worked if I chose to export features in the view extent, as opposed to ALL features.  It worked even if I had the extent such that I get all features.  But I could not export to GDB.  I could only export to Shapefile.